# how to open a new page(window) and copy something from that page without showing it?

Tags: javascript, window.open

**i want to goto the url without showing it then copy something from that page with GetElementById then and show alert with the results**

```
window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
let results = document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml;
alert(results);
```

Comment: `code` let url = 'cnn.com'
`code` let openedWindow = window.open('https://www.google.com/search?`code` q=site:'+url,"_self");
`code` let results = openedWindow.document.querySelector('#result-stats').innerHTML;
//openedWindow.close();
`code` alert(results);
`code` console.log(results);

Comment: my alert are not working still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not a good idea**. This will ONLY WORK when the domain is shared with the opening page (aka, w3schools opening a window on w3schools).

But, here is how you would do it.

```js
let openedWindow = window.open('url');
console.log(openedWindow.document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML);
openedWindow.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**This isn't an answer, just a suggestion**

Why not build a web **scraper** and have it do that for you. Have it send snippets of code and text (the needed data) and put it in a text file or JSON file for later use.

I say this because w3schools.com is pretty consistent with their element names, so minor changes here and there wont hurt. I don't believe that it would open a window, plus there are no built-in limitations on what you can scrape. The only thing you might have to worry about (from off the top of my head) is if the site you plan on **scraping** doesn't allow **scrapers** to get data off their site.

Comment: Scrapper/scrapping are about throwing things away. I think you mean scraper/scraping.